# Tags are not saving in umbraco using blog4umbraco

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

I m using blog4umbraco version 4.5 every thing is working fine but i  am not to able save the tags for blog post there is not any error but tags are not saving, please give me any solution regarding this problem.

Comment: Can you select the tags?  Is it simply that they go away when you press the Save or Save and Publish button?

Comment: when i write the tag name in tags text box then click on save button the tag disappeared from the text box and not saved to anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Do the tags show up in a list below the textbox ever?  You may have to press tab or comma to get the tag to take initially, then press save.